# I wonder why elliptic curve on complex field is a torus

Tags: geometry, elliptic-curves, elliptic-integrals

Let $ E(\mathbb{C})$ be an elliptic curve on $\mathbb{C}$.

$\Lambda $ be a lattices of periods.

I understood the proof of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \to E(\mathbb{C})$ is an isomorphism.
But I think
$\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is 2-dimmensional as vector space over $\mathbb{R}$,
and $E(\mathbb{C})$ is 4-dimensional as vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
What am I missing?

Comment: $E(\mathbb C)$ is a subset of $\mathbb C^2$ (or more generally $\mathbb CP^2$), but that doesn't make it 4-dimensional. A circle is also a subset of the plane, but it's still a 1d object, despite being embedded in a 2d space.